# symfony: How to place the screen on the form error?

Tags: php, forms, symfony

Some of my web pages are very long and have a form at the bottom of the page. Upon sending a form that fails validation, I am brought back to the top of the page, which is not very user friendly.

I would want to find a way to, after an error, place the scroll on the error, or at the top of the form at least.

Does anyone know of a way to control this?

I did, using javascript:

```
{% if not form.vars.valid %}
    window.location.hash = 'form';
{% endif %}
```

I don"t think it is very clean. Do you know of another way?

Comment: You can do this in pure javascript, checking if some hidden element is shown, but I think that there isn't a way to improve this too much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `autofocus` HTML attribute. There's no need for JavaScript to achieve this.

```
<input type="text" name="field_name" autofocus>
```

The attribute can be added like this:

```
{{ form_row(form.field_name, {'attr': {'autofocus': null}}) }}
```

A simple implementation that checks for a field-error might look like this:

```
{% if form.field_name.vars.errors|length %}
  {{ form_row(
       form.field_name, 
       form.field_name.vars|merge({'attr': {'autofocus': null}})
     ) 
  }}
{% else %}
  {{ form_row(form.field_name) }}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: But he only wants this when the form has an error, not always.

Comment: I did not know about this attribute. Looks super neat! Do you know if it is possible to apply it to every fields? (maintenance-wise this solution looks a bit hefty) I was thinking about modifying {% block widget_simple %} but is it ok to place a variable like form.field_name inside?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to add code to each of your field and need a faster and more general solution, this short script will do the job (tested with Symfony3):

```
var delay = 0;
var offset = 150;
if ($('body').find("span").hasClass('help-block')) {
     $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(".help-block").first().offset().top - offset }, delay);
}
```

*offset* allows for a better control of the top position of the target element you're scrolling to (useful if the top of your page is hidden by a fixed nav-bar), and *delay* allows for a delay before scrolling.

Comment: In my case (symfony 5) the class is `form-error-icon` instead of  `help-block`