# How to add an error to a constraint in form?

Tags: forms, symfony

Using Symfony 3.2 on Ubuntu 16.04

I created a FormType.php with several fields. One of them is a phone number, so I added a constraint where only numbers could be accepted. Here is the code for the phone form

```
->add('authorPhone', NumberType::class, array('label' => 'Numéro de téléphone',
                'required' => true,
                'attr' => array(
                    'class' => 'validate',
                    'id' => 'icon_telephone'
                ),
                'constraints' => array(new Regex("#^0[1-9]([-. ]?[0-9]{2}){4}$#"))
            ))
```

After that, in my controller I added an error to tell that numbers only need to be filled in

```
public function indexAction()
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(FormType::class);
        $form->get('authorPhone')->addError(new FormError('error message'));

        return $this->render('app/main/index.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ));
    }
```

But when I look at my page the error message is actually showing without having filled the field. And of course I don't want that.

[image]

(you can see under "Numéro de téléphone", which means phone number)

I only want numbers in my phone number field, and if there are letters, an error should be displayed or something saying it's not right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard how to to this stuff in Symfony is to define an entity with contraints and error messages and then create entity bound form which will handle validation based on entity's contraints automatically.

But if you need, for some reason, independent form, it can be done to. The `addError()` method is for adding error "state" the the form field (e.g. for own validation) and you're adding the error by default right after the form is created. That's the reason why the error shows constantly.

**UPDATED:**

The right way to assign an error message to a form field is by the `invalid_message` property (which is showed when the entered value doesn't correspond with the field type). But when there's a constraint used for validation, then the err message has to be set according to the constraint validator - so, in your case, by associative array with `pattern` and `message` keys.

Next thing need to be corrected is TextType instead of NumberType, because when the NumberType is used, then it won't allow to enter dashes and also automatically trims leading zeros in numbers - so bad for phone numbers :-)

```
->add('authorPhone', TextType::class, array(
    'label' => 'Numéro de téléphone',
    'required' => true,
    'attr' => array(
        'class' => 'validate',
        'id' => 'icon_telephone'
    ),
    'constraints' => array(new Regex(
        array(
            'pattern' => '#^0[1-9]([-. ]?[0-9]{2}){4}$#',
            'message' => 'Phone error message'
        )
    )),
))
```

And last thing to review - in the controller (after form declaration) has to be form submission handling routine:

```
$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
....
```

You can learn more in Symfony's form submission handling: http://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#handling-form-submissions

Form rendering is fairly simple. Twig syntax to render whole form:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
{{ form_widget(form) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

or, if you want to selectively render fields one by one:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
{{ form_row(form.authorPhone) }}
{{ form_row(form.submit) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

It'll renders complete field including labels and errors

Comment: Thank you for your help, I added the line, but how to show it in the view with twig? Should I not add something in the controller? Or something like that {{ form_error(form) }} ? Because at the moment it doesn't do anything and I still can add letters without any error message

Comment: How do you render the forms? Standard symfony's form template renders errors automatically. How's your config in config.yml: twig:form_themes?

Comment: I added this to the controller:
`
$form = $this->createForm(FormType::class);

        return $this->render('app/main/index.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
`

This how I render the form, and in the twig I add this

`
{{ form_row(form.authorPhone) }}
`
as an example

Comment: I'm sorry it seems that I don't know how to format my code here to make it properly readable :/

Comment: So you mean that if I create a form without an entity I should directly put it in the controller? And if I have a form with an entity I do a Form/FormType.php class ?
In my config.yml I have:

`twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"`

Comment: From what I see, everything looks fine. So, lets recaputulate - you access the page, form is rendered, you put "something wrong" into authorPhone field, click Submit and no error shows?

Comment: Yes that is right, no error showed. How should I write my twig section? I have this at the moment `{{ form_row(form.authorPhone) }}
                        {{ form_errors(form) }}`

Comment: I did a little testing and updated the answer. Do not forget to clean Symfony's cache before testing - just for sure.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind help :) I will try that right now. Letting you know if does that work

Comment: But.... I have a little problem :/
I really don't know what to write after `$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {` to handle the form AND the error at the same time, I miss this part. I read all the symfony doc about it but I don't have a clue how to handle it, I'm a student actually.

Comment: `$form->handleRequest($request);` is completely enough to process the form validation. The `if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {}` is for processing the form data after successfull submition and validation, but you can add this later - not needed for our thing now :-)

Comment: It works like a charm but I don't get the original message `Phone error message` instead I get something like `this value is not correct` do you know why?

Comment: Did you make change in the `->add('authorPhone'...` definition as I updated it? Remove the invalid_message and add message into Regexp definition.

Comment: I get an error right here: `'constraints' => array(new Regex(
        'pattern => '#^0[1-9]([-. ]?[0-9]{2}){4}$#'),
        'message' => 'Phone error message'
    ),` Something is missing and its highlighted

Comment: i works! Thank you! :D I can finally go to bed! and you too! haha
Do you have an idea on how to anchor the form if the field is wrong to refresh directly on the form itself? :) And how to color the error?

Comment: What do you mean with anchor? And more on form styling is here https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html#what-are-form-themes

Comment: I mean that if I have an error on the form, like on the phone number, when I click `submit` instead of being refreshedat the top of the page, I am refreshed exactly where the form is on the page.

Comment: Undestood, you can do this by the autofocus propety of an input tag, which you set only if there is an error on the field. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30452987/symfony-how-to-place-the-screen-on-the-form-error

Comment: Thank you for all your help! :) I validated your answer +1 kudos. Appreciated Honza